# How to store multiple Profile Pictures in NodeJS & Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm new to mongodb, so pls go easy.

Let's say that I am creating a website where, in creating profile, users can provide multiple profile images which would be presented in a way of carousel later when other check their profile. Let's say the first picture user uploaded should be the first image in the carousel.

And user are allowed to alter the order of images showing by dragging forward or backward in editing session in order to decide which image to be showed first. The key is the order is editable

According to what I learnt so far, I have created a simple document structure to store user's information as below, where username and profile_image were stored.

But, in this way, I am stuck with one picture only. May I know how should I alter the table, so that it allow to store multiple images, as well as the order of images.

May I know what I should do to implement my original function? Is it should be done by making another table to store order?

When I'm saying the order is editable, I'm saying something like this https://i2.wp.com/www.techjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/4-2-scaled.jpg?resize=690%2C1401&ssl=1

```
[   { username: 'username_1',
      profile_image: 'path_of_the_image',
    },
    { username: 'username_2',
      profile_image: 'path_of_the_image',
    }

]
```

Comment: Hi @hose, Not sure exactly what are you looking for. But i think you need to edit the image sequence to show in the carousel view. For that you can store the sequence of the image along with image path in the database whenever you drag and drop the image.

Comment: hi @PHPGeek , For capturing the images' order part, I dont quite follow. If user alter the order of imgaes, how could I keep track of it ? I have updated a bit of desciption above, hope it is a bit clear now,  FYI, when I said users can edit the order, I m saying something like this https://i2.wp.com/www.techjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/4-2-scaled.jpg?resize=690%2C1401&ssl=1

Comment: You can store the profile image data in an array, e.g., `profile_images: [ 'url_1', 'úrl_2', ... ]`. Another way is: `profile_images: [ { url: 'url_1', other_data: 'abc' }, { url: 'url_2', other_data: 'xyz' }, ... ]`.

Comment: @prasad_ if it is possible that, you may provide some reference/example about implementation of handling the orders in the array. For example, how would be the nosql or node.js statement looks like for such use cases. Coz it seems it would be a lot more complex than the example i have just learnt so far. I really want to see some example to get some hints to do that.

Comment: An array can be sorted based upon a field value. What is the ordering criteria/data in your case?

Comment: @prasad_  ,In the final use case, the order would be arranged by the orders that user arrange the image. For now, in my mock dataset, I was think sth like : profile_images: [ { url: 'url_1', position: 1 }, { url: 'url_2', position: '2' }, ... ] ; then when users rearrange the order like this https://i2.wp.com/www.techjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/4-2-scaled.jpg?resize=690%2C1401&ssl=1 ; the position fields will be updated.   But in this way, i cant never make use of the sort function....